# add a div between header and footer that takes up rest of the view height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to add a div between the header and footer. Both are flex boxes, however the div in between (which in the end needs to be a slider) does not get positioned well. I am trying to get the header on top and the slider to fill up the remaining space of the view height. Only on the scroll it should show the footer (and eventually other div's as well). Somehow I have the feeling flex box is not working correctly..

Basically the same effect as this website: [ArsThanea](http://www.arsthanea.com).

Another problem that I have when opening the JSFiddle is that the header and footer do not take the complete width of the view box, although the div does. When running the html and css in the browser using Gulp / Jekyll it works and it takes up the complete width.

```css
header {
  height: 130px;
  background: white;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
}
header .logo img {
  height: 73px;
  width: 146px;
  padding-left: 60px;
}
header p {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'StratumNo1';
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 50px;
}
header .site-nav {
  margin-left: auto;
}
header .site-nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
}
header .site-nav ul li {
  display: inline;
  font-family: 'StratumNo1';
  color: black;
  margin: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
}
header .site-nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
header .site-nav ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
header .site-nav ul li a:first-child {
  margin: 0px 10px 0 0;
}
header .search-form {
  width: 300px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
header .search-form .search-input {
  width: 240px;
  border-bottom: black 1px solid;
  border-left: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  border-top: 0;
  font-family: 'StratumNo1';
  font-size: 14px;
}
header .search-form .search-input:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
.footer-lockup {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #1d1c1c;
  width: 100%;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}
.footer-lockup .copyright {
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans Light';
  margin-left: 60px;
  color: #4d4c4c;
  width: auto;
}
.footer-lockup ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin-right: 60px;
  padding: 0;
}
.footer-lockup ul li {
  display: inline;
  font-family: 'Open Sans Light';
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.footer-lockup ul li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0px;
}
.footer-lockup ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #4d4c4c;
}
.social-logos {
  position: relative;
  min-width: 200px;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}
.social-logos .social-logo {
  height: 20px;
  min-width: 20px;
  margin-right: 18px;
}
.social-logos .social-logo:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.social-logos .social-logo .social-media {
  text-align: center;
  height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.social-logos .social-logo img {
  height: 20px;
}
.social-logos .social-logo img.youtube {
  height: 35px;
  margin-top: -7px;
}
.projects-wrapper {
  display: block;
  background: pink;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 130px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="/assets/img/YourLogo.svg" />
  </div>
  <p>Your Placeholder Text</p>
  <nav class="site-nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#Home">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#About Us">About Us</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#Services">Services</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#Work">Work</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#Contact">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <form class="search-form">
    <input placeholder="What are you looking for?" type="search" name="search-input" class="search-input" />
  </form>
</header>

<div class="projects-wrapper"></div>


<footer>
  <div class="footer-lockup">
    <p class="copyright">© 2016 “Your Company Name” All rights reserved</p>

    <div class="social-logos">
      <div class="social-logo">
        <div class="social-media">
          <img src="/assets/img/behance-icon.svg" />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="social-logo">
        <div class="social-media">
          <img src="/assets/img/facebook-icon.svg" />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="social-logo">
        <div class="social-media">
          <img src="/assets/img/linkedin-icon.svg" />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="social-logo">
        <div class="social-media">
          <img src="/assets/img/twitter-icon.svg" />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="social-logo">
        <div class="social-media">
          <img src="/assets/img/youtube-icon.svg" class="youtube" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <ul>
      <li><a href="#Home">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#About Us">About Us</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#Services">Services</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#Work">Work</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#Contact">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
</footer>
```

DEMO: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7yLFL/800/)

Comment: Flex box might be a good option for you: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: thats what I am trying, however it does not seems to work the way I want.

Comment: Q. is there any way to do it without flexbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a look at your Fiddle, there are many improvements you can make to your markup & CSS, but coming to your issue first, the reason why its not sliding down as expected is this :

> `position: absolute`

you added this to your main div which should go in between `.projects-wrapper`. First thing I would say is make this a flex as well instead of block element.

Secondly, add a wrapper to your entire project body & **Make that flex**. like so

```
<div class="wrapper"> //this should be flex
  <header>..</header> //this "could" be flex depending on its contents
  <div class="projects-wrapper"></div>
  <footer>...</footer> //this "could" be flex depending on its contents
</div>
```

let me know if you are facing any other problems

Comment: thanks for your answer, however what I am experiencing now is when adding a wrapper to the entire project, the footer shows up next to the header. So I have to slide to the right to see the footer.

Btw; could you make a working fiddle for your answer, so I can see what you did and what changes this brings to my work? 

And is it better to use flex box for these kind of things or just stick with inline-block and normal floats left or right?

Comment: yes i know what you mean, the header is going right because in flex the "default" direction of the elements flowing is **row(horizontal)**. you need to change this as `flex-direction: column`(vertical) for your wrapper. I am really glad you are brave enough to use flexbox though, you will know down the line how it helps you big time. Many people just stay away from it because they don't know much about it

Comment: I think I have found the solution, although I am not sure if this is the correct way to do this. [JSFiddle]: (http://jsfiddle.net/7yLFL/807/). I am trying to learn code on my own, could you tell me what improvement I could make to my code? Are there unnecessary things mentioned? Thanks again :)

Comment: yes this is exactly the right way to do it. Improvements could be minor, instead of using height on your `<header>` & `<footer>` you could make use of `padding`. Always avoid `position: absolute` unless its absolutely necessary. I have given a talk on Flexbox, here is the document I have created for the same. Have a look - https://github.com/NikhilNanjappa/NikhilNanjappa.github.io/blob/master/flexbox.md. It has a complete tutorial/links for better understanding flexbox

Comment: Thanks, will definitely read the document. Why is padding better to use than height? Has this any relation to flex box? And only use padding on headers and footers?

Comment: No relation at al, your flexbox seems fine. relating to flexbox always use a `wrapper` like how you did & control the elements inside it using the wrapper. You can also use `flex-basis: 100%;` instead of `width`. Here is a brilliant interactive tutorial which will teach you how to control elements inside a flexbox - http://flexboxfroggy.com/. Don't worry much about it now, you are already doing great. Just continue using more.

Answer (score 0):

I made code for You, please have a look, and tell mi is it good for You.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7yLFL/806/)

I use `calc()` to do that

Answer (score 0):

Use 100vh to get the 100% view-port height and subtract the height of header and footer.

```
min-height: calc(100vh - 50px);
```

where 50px is the height of header+footer.
partial support for [ie](http://caniuse.com/#search=vh)